# MessageResources in struts not working for asian languages...but returns ?????? instead

Tags: localization, resources, struts, message

MessageResources in struts not working for asian languages...but returns ?????? instead.How do I handle that,as it's working fine for other languages.

Comment: Do you have a properties file for each of these languages?

Answer (score 0):

I would read up on MessageResources - this is a useful article http://www.selbyinc.com/technology/struts-messageresources.html

If you don't have a default messages.properties file then you need to have one for every user locale, called (for example) messages_languagecode.properties (e.g. for English, messages_en.properties)